Schedule GitHub action run for the future
I have a Git-based CMS system that manages events.
Each event has details about in in a file on Git.
name: 'My event'
start_time: 'September 13th, 5pm'

Right when the event starts, I want to start a GitHub action - workflow_trigger (docs).
This GitHub action will trigger a webhook and send an email to everyone.
GitHub has a 'schedule' trigger: (docs) I could use to hack around this:
on:
  schedule:
    # * is a special character in YAML so you have to quote this string
    - cron:  '30 5,17 * * *'
  # one cron job per event, have a bot commit this file

Is there a better way to schedule an action to run at a specified time? Potentially another system inside GitHub that can run at a specific time, and then I can use an event trigger based on that system event happening?
